# How to give style to ngb-bootstrap tab

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

At the moment I'm using **ng-bootstrap** into Angular 2 project.
I need to change pills color on **ngb-tab**. I tried put label **style** on the element but it doesn't work. Can you help me?

Example:

```html
<ngb-tab *ngIf="isNotPending" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)">
    <template ngbTabContent>
       <div id="img_centered" class="col-md-12">
         <img style="padding: 30px;" src="assets/images/happy.PNG" alt="Hello" >
        </div>
     </template>
</ngb-tab>
```

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

You could be importing a stylesheet for whatever library `ngb-tab` is in and those style end up loading after your local stylesheets. Or there could be some compilation of `ngb-tab` which is adding other elements.

There are a couple of ways to resolve this depending on the issue.

Look for the `<link>` tag and "CDN". Once it's in your local project stylesheets then you can modify it OR You could also use the `!important` declaration in your local stylesheet:

```
ngb-tab { 
   background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); /* come on brah, use #fff */
}
```

If the cascade (**CSS** = **C**ascading **S**tyle**S**heets) isn't the issue then inspect your DOM to see if you are actually trying to change the color of the correct element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I applied this style I change the other tabs. I need to show this tab only if *ngIf="isNotPending" and change color.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead.. write CSS in global CSS file in your project... OR remove import file "styleUrls:['./example.component.css']" and write CSS class inside component.ts file with styles: ['.example{ Some css... }']

Answer (score 0):

Try this code --
i try to use css, but font tag works here.

```
 <ng-template  ngbTabTitle class="edittitle">  <font size="3" color="red">  <b>Edit</b></font> </ng-template>
```